# ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,) doesn't match the broadcast shape (0,)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to understand the mergeSort algorithm and ran the code provided on this link (https://medium.com/@ssbothwell/counting-inversions-with-merge-sort-4d9910dc95f0)

**However, I get the error ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,) doesn't match the broadcast shape (0,)**

I am unable to understand why this occurs as the code works on smaller examples like arr = [1, 20, 6, 4, 5]. (The array test contains 50 random numbers)

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? And can someone also please explain when we get shape(0,)? Is it when the array is empty?

```
test = numbers[0:50]

def mergeSortInversions(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr, 0
    else:
        mid = len(arr)//2
        a = arr[:mid]
        b = arr[mid:]
        a, ai = mergeSortInversions(a)
        b, bi = mergeSortInversions(b)
        c = []
        i = 0
        j = 0
        inversions = 0 + ai + bi
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
        if a[i] <= b[j]:
            c.append(a[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            c.append(b[j])
            j += 1
            inversions += (len(a)-i)
    c += a[i:]
    c += b[j:]
    return c, inversions

arr = [1, 20, 6, 4, 5] 
#print('test', np.shape(test))
x, inv = mergeSortInversions(test)    
print(inv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out, you can't add elements to an empty array.

I solved it using the condition

```
if len(a[i:]) != 0:
   c += a[i:]
```